# Include join table data after creating new entry using sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 3 tables Inventories, Items, and InventoryItems(A junction table with the attribute qty). I want to be able to add a new entry into the InventoryItems and include the Item information associated to it from the Item table in one request is that possible? My current solution is to create the item then query a second time for the item with it's included information -

```
  const itemToCreate = {
        inventoryId,
        itemId,
        qty,
  }

  const addedInventoryItem = await InventoryItem.create(itemToCreate);

  const query = {
    where : {
      inventoryId,
      itemId
    },
    attributes: ['qty'],
    include : {
      association : 'itemInfo', //alias for Item Model
      attributes : ['name', 'description']
    }
  }

  const fullItemInfo = await InventoryItem.findOne(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use promises chaining like this .

```
const itemToCreate = {
    inventoryId,
    itemId,
    qty,
}

const query = {
    where: {
        inventoryId,
        itemId
    },
    attributes: ['qty'],
    include: {
        association: 'itemInfo', //alias for Item Model
        attributes: ['name', 'description']
    }
}

InventoryItem
    .create(itemToCreate)
    .then(function () {
        InventoryItem
            .findOne(query)
            .spread(function (InventoryItem, created) {
                console.log(InventoryItem.get({
                    plain: true
                }))
                console.log(created);
            })
    })
```